# How to get the pictures from folder one by one and display in the page using PHP

Tags: php, image

How to fetch the images from a folder and display it in the page, whether i can resize it in php itself or i have to resize it and upload it separtely to display it as thumbnails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the basic structure for traversing a directory and doing something with the image files (given `'images'` is a directory in the same directory of your script)

```
$image_types = array(
    'gif' => 'image/gif',
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
);

foreach (scandir('images') as $entry) {
    if (!is_dir($entry)) {
        if (in_array(mime_content_type('images/'. $entry), $image_types)) {
            // do something with image
        }
    }
}
```

From here, you can send the images directly to browser, generate  tags for HTML page or create thumbnails with [GD functions](http://www.php.net/gd) and store them for displaying.

Comment: Take note that this solution uses deprecated `mime_content_type` function which needs mime_magic php modules. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but the `for` loop doesn't seem to be valid Php and I think should be `foreach( scandir('images') as $entry)`.

Comment: @emileb Corrected the loop syntax.

Answer (score 7):

i think this may help you!

```
<?
$string =array();
$filePath='directorypath/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
   if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) { 
   $string[] = $file;
   }
}
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
  $img = array_pop($string);
  echo "<img src='$filePath$img'  width='100px'/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`eregi` is deprecated now so you can use `preg_match` instead

```
<?php
$string =array();
$filePath='directorypath/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
   if (preg_match("/.png/",$file) || preg_match("/.jpg/",$file) || preg_match("/.gif/",$file) ) { 
   $string[] = $file;
   }
}
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
  $img = array_pop($string);
  echo "<img src='$filePath$img' >";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

To resize images directly from PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8414867/1218980) to a similar question:

```
// this will get you full path to images file.
$data = glob("path/to/images/*.{jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

// this will get you only the filenames
$data= array_map('basename', $data);
```

Originally, I wanted to use [@Imran solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215858/1218980), but `mime_content_type` wasn't available and the server (on which I have zero control) uses old versions of Apache and Php.

So I changed it a little to work with file extension instead and I'm giving it here.

```
$imgDir = "images_dir";

// make sure it's a directory
if (file_exists($imgDir)) {

    // select the extensions you want to take into account
    $image_ext = array(
            'gif',
            'png',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg'
    );

    foreach (scandir($imgDir) as $entry) {
        if (! is_dir($entry)) { // no need to weed out '.' and '..'
            if (in_array(
                    strtolower(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), 
                    $image_ext)) {

                // do something with the image file.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is tested and is working.