# Get filenames of images in a directory

Tags: php, opendir

What should be done to get titles (eg abc.jpg) of images from a folder/directory using PHP and storing them in an array.

For example:

```
a[0] = 'ac.jpg'
a[1] = 'zxy.gif'
```

etc.

I will be using the array in a slide show.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's certainly possible. Have a look at [the documentation for opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and push every file to a result array. If you're using PHP5, have a look at [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php). It is a much smoother and cleaner way to traverse the contents of a directory!

**EDIT:** Building on *opendir*:

```
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $images = array();

        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if (!is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                $images[] = $file;
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);

        print_r($images);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

'scandir' does this:

```
$images = scandir($dir);
```

Comment: scandir is safest than glob because directory can contain regex chars

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?! Beautiful one liner.

Comment: its also returning "." and ".." any better way to skip it in a loop?

Answer (score 5):

One liner :-

```
$arr = glob("*.{jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE)
```

Answer (score 4):

[glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) in php - **Find pathnames matching a pattern**

```
<?php
    //path to directory to scan
    $directory = "../images/team/harry/";
    //get all image files with a .jpg extension. This way you can add extension parser
    $images = glob($directory . "{*.jpg,*.gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $listImages=array();
    foreach($images as $image){
        $listImages=$image;
    }
?>
```