# php image url from folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I want all the images from some_folder to be displayed as slideshow..

but i dont know how to go about it...

I found a same question [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414746/get-filenames-of-images-in-a-directory) but..since i am not so familiar with php finding it difficult..

is there a plugin for slide show of images..?

i googled and found Nextgen and wp-cycle...but some problem with plugin or dont know the images arent getting loaded in case of Nextgen and incase of wp-cycle only first image is loaded .

can anyone help me regarding same??

**EDIT1**

When i try to install Nivo i get following message:

[image]

and one more big problem is that..
in wordpress pages and post i am not able to see the Visual tab..

i have no idea suddenly visual tab is not getting opened..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery plugins such as [Nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). Or you can follow this [link](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/03/20-professional-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/).

Comment: @pradnya which browser are you using? Give me some more details.

Comment: i am using mozilla firefox....but it should work in all web browsers..
i have installed many plugins..is it because of that..??

Comment: I have used most of plugin. It dint happened to me. can you please edit above question and post code with it?

Comment: @pradnya Have you downloaded [wordpress plugin](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/features/#wordpress) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14322/discussion-between-vinay-and-pradnya)