# Remove characters from array output

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of images being displayed from a specific directory using the following code:

```
<?php 
    $dir = "img";
    $files = scandir($dir); 
    echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($files, true)), "</pre>\n";  
?>
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => image_1.png
    [3] => image_2.png
    [4] => image_3.png
)
```

What I would like to do is display the array of images as shown below thus removing `[x] =>` for each image and also removing `Array ( )`.

```
image_1.png
image_2.png
image_3.png
```

Im not sure how to go about this. I have never really worked with arrays before therefore the only methods I can think of are `preg_replace()` or `str_replace()`, but honestly not sure where I would start.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215799/how-to-get-the-pictures-from-folder-one-by-one-and-display-in-the-page-using-php You can do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(join("\n", $files)), "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: thank you for the quick and simple response. works like a charm. will accept answer when I'm allowed to.

Comment: And quick way to remove `.` and `..`: `$files = array_diff( scandir($dir), array('.', '..') );`

Comment: @Fabio: much appreciated. just to let you know, you forgot a single quote within the array ;)